# How to generate read-only PresignedUrl in AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

```
var getPreSignedUrlRequest = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest()
                    {
                        BucketName = this._appSettings.AWS_S3_IMAGE_SIGNATURE_BUCKET,
                        Key = fileKey,
                        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24),
                        Verb = HttpVerb.GET,
                        // ContentType = "application/octet-stream",
                        ServerSideEncryptionMethod = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.AES256,

                    };
```

So I wanna create a presignedUrl to read an image in S3 bucket with read-only permission, but if i make a request like above code (even with the verb GET), I can still use this presignedUrl to Upload a new image to replace the old one. Is there any way to prevent user to overwrite an object with PresignedUrl (for read-only purpose)?

Comment: Try removing the Verb and the ServerSideEncryptionMethod from the constructor.

Comment: @kgiannakakis still not work

Comment: What makes you think that a pre-signed GET URL allows you to replace the existing object? There is no way that a GET request will update an object.

Comment: Is there a bucket policy on that S3 bucket? Something must be giving permission to `PutObject` otherwise the upload would fail.

Comment: @jarmod I can change it to PUT in Postman and upload a new file replace the old one.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein so i think there no way to generate a read-only presignedUrl. we might prevent overwrite file by changing the folder policy

Comment: Every pre-signed URL will only work for the action that is encoded in the URL. It should _only_ work to `GET` the file. If you are able to upload a file using the same URL, then your bucket must allowing 'public' uploads, because that pre-signed URL certainly isn't doing it!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and a lot of people couldn't explain it properly so I'll try to do that.

By creating an s3 presigned URL, you're attaching a token with the permissions of the user who created that URL. So if the user has write access, you're basically allowing public write to that object until the URL expires.

More on it [here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html#PresignedUrlUploadObject-LimitCapabilities)

A possible solution is to use `CloudFront`'s signed URLs and point them to your S3 objects.